# How to handling system shortcut keydown event in mac os

Tags: macos, swift, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I need get the system shortcut keyboard keydown value, so I use

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    println(theEvent.characters)
    println(theEvent.modifierFlags.rawValue)
}
```

but it not working for many shortcut, for example. command + m, when I push this shortcut, the app will hide in dock, and no any value print in debug window.

one more problem is, if focus in a textfield. this function will not working, how can I solve it?